# Compare two matrices' Hamming distace

Tags: matrices

It may seem a silly question that, how to compare two matrices with the same dimension by Hamming distance?

$$d^{HD}(i,j) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [y_{ik}\neq y_{jk} ]$$

- Is it Simply `sum(abs(B-A))` where `A` and `B` are the matrices?
- Is it used for weighted matrices or just used for binary ones?

In some packages like `Scipy`, `pdist(X,"hamming")`

*Computes the normalized Hamming distance, or the proportion of those vector elements between two **n-vectors** `u` and `v` which disagree. To save memory, the matrix `X` can be of type boolean.
The output is a matrix n by n(`squareform`).*

I don't know how to apply for matrices?